# Please help me understand this line of code

Tags: java, object, csv, io

```
CSVParser csvParser = null;
String csvFilename = "C:\\Users\\ITEM.txt20141022";


csvParser = new CSVParser(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilename)), CSVFormat.newFormat('|'));
```

The algorithm as far as I understand it:

1. The FileReader object is passed to the BufferedReader constructor.
2. The BufferedReader object is passed to the CSVParser constructor. This would be one of the two parameters passed to the csvParser?
3. the second csvParser parameter is CSVFormat.newFormat('|')

Would this line be considered two parameters that are passed to the csvParser Object? These two parameters are then used in the csvParser constructor? I have looked at the javadocs and am failing to understand how all these pieces fit together to instantiate the CSVParser. How would you know this is possible in the first place? I have been taking a beginner java class for a couple of weeks now and I've never seen anything like this. Could someone please explain to me how this line works as if you were talking to a 5 year old.

Comment: You would look at the javadoc of CSVParser and see it there is a constructor accepting a BufferedReader or a Reader as first argument, and, presumably, a CSVFormat (assuming that's what is returned by `newFormat()`) as second argument. There are dozens of different classes named CSVParser, so we don't know which one you're using.

Comment: Looks to me like you've figured it out.  Which `CSVParser` is this, the one from Apache Commons, with [this constructor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#CSVParser-java.io.Reader-org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat-)?

Comment: Yes I am using the Apache commons. I've heard that this is recommended if possible. Is this correct? Use an apache commons class if I can. The explanation I got was that it is tried and true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it correct, as near as I can tell.

This programmer is invoking constructors in place of declaring objects of correct type, instantiating objects to put in the object variables, and then using the variables.  It could also be written as:

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.newFormat('|');
FileReader reader = new FileREader(csvFilename);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(bReader, format);
```

I'm assuming the type returned by the first method call.

Hope that's more clear.  It's how I would have written it...

Comment: This is SOOO much easier to understand. Wow, thank you. Now I need to work through how he shortened it. Thanks again.

Comment: @stackoverflow1 it's easier for newcomers to the language. But any developer with just a little bit of Java experience understands your original code just fine. Experienced Java developers would probably find the "simplified" code too verbose and introducing useless variables.

Comment: SOME experienced Java developers might think so.  I have programmed in Java for 15 years, and I STILL find the original easier to understand, debug, and ensure is correct.  And the only difference in the variables introduced is that the explicit ones are visible.  They occupy no extra memory space, take negligible time to compile, etc. -- there are no technical reasons to do this the first way, and several software engineering reasons for the second way.  For instance: it gives the writer a chance to name the parameters so they describe things better.

Comment: Ok after looking this I have one question. The absence of the extra variables means you don't have to declare a type for each one? Why is this possible? Is it like piping things in unix? Like using pipes instead of temp files.

Comment: Because Java is strongly typed, constructors and methods each return an object of a specific type (or the method can return null, not useful in this case).  The object constructed or returned also matches other types -- any superclasses and any interfaces implemented.  When the result of one of these is used as a parameter, the compiler spends some time figuring out whether any of the matched types matches any of the parameters to the constructor being called (or to help determine which constructor to call).

Comment: @arcy there are very good reasons to avoid those useless variables. Not having them makes sure you don't mistakenly read from the file reader or the buffered reader instead of reading from the CSVParser. Chaining constructors and method calls is very common in Java. It can be abused, like everything else, but I wouldn't say this is an abuse.

Comment: Whether it qualifies as an "abuse" I won't quibble with.  But the OP said "This is SOOO much easier to understand."  The variables are not "useless", they aid understanding.  And if you read from the wrong thing, that is a bug found immediately and fixed easily.  Code that is harder to understand comes with a cost, and the software industry in general doesn't consider that strongly enough.  The fact that it is common says nothing about whether it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

CSVParser constructor takes two arguments as below:

```
CSVParser(Reader reader, CSVFormat format)
```

Now follow the code carefully, should be easy to understand, take care of the parentheses